# Почему компилятор Go не видит подключенный сторонний пакет?

Tags: golang

OS Windows.

`GOPATH = C:\Users\User\go\`

Устанавливаю сторонний пакет: `go install github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@latest`

Встал нормально.
Но, при компиляции ошибка: `go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory`.

Почему так? Помимо инсталляции пакета, нужно ещё что-то колдовать с файлом `go.mod`? Или в чём дело?

Попробовал сделать файл go.mod: `go mod init github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`

Вроде сделалось. Но всё равно не компилируется: "`$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not`".

UPD. Редактор VS Code тоже пишет ошибку:

```
Failed to run 'C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe env' (cwd: undefined): Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe env -json GOPATH GOROOT GOPROXY GOBIN GOMODCACHE
$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
```

Comment: *"go.mod file not found"* никак не соответствует заголовку вопроса, никаких жалоб на сторонние пакеты. Читайте документацию про модули в go.

Comment: Тогда как сформулировать вопрос? Я инсталлировал пакет, но у компилятора с ним проблема... - какая? И как инсталлировать, чтобы проблемы не было?

Comment: Сначала описана ошибка "go.mod file not found" (которая может и не соответствует заголовку), но ниже уже другая - "go.mod exists but should not". Или обе ошибки не о том?

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, вот у тебя проект до инициализации go.mod

[[image: До инициализации go.mod3]

Попробуем собрать, получим ошибку "go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory"

[image: Ошибка]

Теперь выполним инициализацию, при помощи:

```
go mod init ИМЯ_ТВОЕГО_ПРОЕКТА
```

и теперь проект будет собираться без ошибок.

После инициализации (go mod init) можно уже подтянуть нужную тебе либу и использовать ее, выполняем:

```
 go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@latest
```

после этого у тебя сгенерирует файлик go.sum, а в go.mod добавиться информация о зависимости от подтянутой либы и ты сможешь спокойно ее использовать:

[image]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: У меня компилировалось и без go mod init ИМЯ_ТВОЕГО_ПРОЕКТА. Пока я не начал ставить сторонний пакет. После как появился (нормально вставший) стор. пакет - начались ошибки. То "нет файла go.mod", то "файл есть, но опять не то"... Я хочу понять: для работы со сторонним пакетом обязательно надо колдовать в go.mod? (Раньше я без этого обходился, но не помню как тогда делал.)

Comment: теперь на go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@latest он пишет:
go: package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql is in the main module, so can't request version latest . Хотя раньше ставилось нормально (командой go install, сейчас ею тоже не ставится, там другую ошибку пишет).

Comment: А у меня твой пример и build'ится и run'ится нормально, без go.mod. :) Хотя это не суть, конечно.

Comment: Помогло в итоге. Спасибо! Надо было сначала go.mod инициировать, а потом инсталлировать пакет, а я наоборот делал, поэтому ошибки и были про go.mod.

Comment: Возможно это зависит от версии компиля и от того как компилишь, но для полноценных проектов я бы советовал сразу проводить инициализацию

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно работать вне `$GOPATH`. Начиная с `go` v1.11 эта папка используется для кэширования модулей и установки бинарников командой `go install`. Свой код в `$GOPATH` уже давно не разрабатывают.

Перенесите свой проект в какую-нибудь другую папку, например `C:\work\go` - конкретное имя не важно. Нужно только, чтобы эта папка была вне пути `C:\Users\User\go\`

В папке `C:\work\go` создайте `go.mod`:

```
go mod init my-project
```

Имя, стоящее после `init` использует `go build` для имени собираемого исполнимого файла.

Проверьте, что `go.mod` есть. Теперь можете добавлять стороннюю библиотеку:

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@latest
```

В последнее время команды `go get` и `go install` развели - теперь `go install` устанавливает бинарник (то есть скачивает, компилирует, сохраняет результат в `$GOPATH/bin`), но не добавляет модуль в зависимости. Для добавления зависимости используйте `go get`.

Теперь всё должно компилироваться.

PS. Странно, что команда `go install` у вас сработала. Так быть не должно.
Вот что мне выдал `go` v1.21:

```
$ go install github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@latest
go: downloading github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.7.1
package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql is not a main package
```

Comment: Решил. Надо было всего лишь go.mod инициализировать ДО установки стороннего пакета (а вообще сразу при создании проекта), а я инициализировал его ПОСЛЕ. И работаю в директории GOPATH (может это и неправильно, но у меня работает). Инициализировал go.mod и с именем файла-проекта, и с именем директории (GOPATH) - одинаково нормально работает.